# Using Links in iOS Fullscreen Web Apps

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, homescreen

I'm working on a quick landing page to access a number of small, mobile-optimized applications on the same server. Basically the Dashboard pattern. I want to have it on my home screen so that I can get to any of the apps in fullscreen mode rather than in toolbar-heavy mobile Safari. However, when I click on a link, it takes me out of the fullscreen mode into Safari -- exactly what I don't want.

Is there a way (e.g. using an anchor's `target` attribute) to stay in the fullscreen mode while navigating to a different page? Or should I just throw everything into an `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to intercept the `onclick` event using some javascript. For example, here's what [iWebKit](http://iwebkit.net) does with the `noeffect` css class applied to an `<a>` tag:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function fullscreen() {
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length;i++) {
            if (a[i].className.match("noeffect")) {
                // Does nothing
            }
            else {
                a[i].onclick = function () {
                    window.location = this.getAttribute("href");
                    return false;
                };
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out a while back. But thanks for the answer! Good to have it up there. I did more experiments with frames, forms and events, so I should put the results of those here, too.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever an `onclick` occurs in mobile Safari, Safari will take it out of fullscreen mode. Form submissions will remain in fullscreen mode, whether `POST` or `GET`. If `window.location` is set via javascript, it will also remain in fullscreen mode.

I prefer delegation to setting an event handler on each anchor. Here's a jQuery example:

```
$(window).click(handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
    var target = $(e.target).closest('a');
    if( target ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = target.attr('href');
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Delegation is much more efficient, clean, and reusable than looping through all the anchors and adding event listeners to each of them manually.